Connect to SFTP server with a public key
I have a host, a username and a public key as a string. How can I connect to the server?
PhpStorm asks me for the private key file, but I have a public key string.
Should I put the public key into a file and upload it as a private key?
Thanks!

How do you connect to that server otherwise?

with a private key, but i think that i must create a public key for the user that i need, but i don't know how i can do

If you use a private key otherwise, why not use it in PhpStorm?

The server will be unable to authenticate you if all you have is a public key. You will have to generate a new keypair.

i have this command: cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@host 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys', i think that this is for linux, how can i write it for windows?

That command is used to write your public key onto any external server. This has to be done once, and can also be done by editing the file manually
